# Windows 10 install log on non-booting machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-pe

My Windows 10 laptop suddenly stopped booting.
It booted up normally at first, with all the autostart(mostly win32) apps launched working ok, however Forza Horizon wouldn’t start. I restarted, and wasn’t able to get it to boot since.

All of the options in WinPE (apart from the reinstall) were tried. Update rollback didn’t work. sfc found no issues, DISM didn't work in PE. Start up repair didn’t work. Safe mode won't boot either. Couldn’t find the ntbtlog after enabling boot logging, so presume that didn't work either. System restore didn’t work (0x80070026, failed to extract directory - renaming WindowsApps did not fix).

I’ve recently installed iTunes 11 (win32) instead of the one from MS Store, as well as libusb and a minor update to a driver checker. System Restore also shows an update (25.0->26.0) for an update (KB4023057) - not sure if it affects anything.
Could anyone advise what other ways there are to check the boot/install log from WinPE? Did I miss any options (apart from a reinstall) in my process?
UPD1
OS was installed on disk 1, volume 1, and currently has D: assigned to it in PE.
I've manually assigned S: to the system volume, however was unable to remove the hidden attribute.
When I then did

```
bcdboot D:\windows /s S: /f UEFI
ren S:\EFI\Microsoft\boot\bcd bcd.old
Bootrec  /RebuildBcd
```

bootrec was able to see a Windows installation in D:/Windows. So I selected that to rebuild bcd, thinking that since an installation was found where I expect it to be, I might be out of the woods. Nope, rebooting and getting the same failed boot, this time without the 0x000001c error though.
Listing volumes in diskpart, I can see the system partition no longer has a letter (S) assigned to it, ans scanos doesn't see the OS in D: again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

huh. So I replaced the hives from the shadow copy and just rebooted into a working OS. I am still getting entry point errors for some Apple software, but that was happening before.
now just need to try and compare the registry hives to see what went wrong